# Annihilation Subtlety in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Currently reading through Robert Klauber's Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory and he got me wondering about electron-positron annihilation.

In Chapter 8 he goes over the expansion of the S-Operator. He uses examples like Bhabha scattering, which includes a second-order diagram for electron/positron annihilation, showing an incoming electron/positron pair annihilating and producing a virtual photon followed by creation of another pair of outgoing electron/positron pair.

*Here's my current hang-up:*  In the expansion of the S-operator, he demonstrates that 1-vertex interactions are NOT physical, which seems to mean an electron/positron pair CANNOT annihilate to produce a *real* photon.

*Does that mean all **physically realizable** electron/positron pair annihilation MUST be followed by another pair being created?*

Otherwise it's a 1-vertex interaction, right?

Comment: No, because electron/positron pairs can annihilate to more than one photon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an electron and position can also realistically annihilate into *two* real photons via this second-order scattering process (where time runs downward in the diagram):

[image]

Comment: Ahh, simple enough!  Thanks @tparker, I wasn't aware of this interaction.